# How to upgrade Spark version on AWS EMR cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, amazon-emr

My application uses Spark 2.4.X (scala 2.11.X) and Hbase 2.X. I didn't find any EMR release that matches my application needs. I taught on using EMR release 6.0 which includes HBase 2.2.3, but what is the best way to install the specific Spark version?

Answer (score 0):

Each AWS EMR comes with specific versions of Spark and Hbase installed. Please see this link for reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-app-versions-6.x.html

Looks like 2 suitable versions for your requirements would be : emr-6.0.0 OR emr-6.0.1